# How to structure nodejs code properly

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, node.js

I've been playing with node.js for a while, and I've really come to appreciate how awesome it is. However, one thing I'm struggling to understand is how I should structure my code so that it is maintainable. Most tutorials I've seen on the internet have all the JS in one file, which is hardly a nice way to manage your code. I am aware there is no such thing in real-terms as a "class" in javascript, but is there a (standard) way for me to format my code for maintainability in the same way I'd structure a PHP project, for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Afaik you can use `require` to include your own js files (containing exported methods) using:

```
var req = require('./someJsFile');
```

Within `someJsFile.js` you can export methods like this:

```
exports.someMethod = function(){ /*...*/ };
```

And in your main file you can address such a method using `req.someMethod()`

So this way you can split up your code in different files, which you `require` from some central js file.

[Here is an article](http://jherdman.github.com/2010-04-05/understanding-nodejs-require.html) explaining node.js `require`

Answer (score 12):

I'd add that as far as maintainability goes, I believe the typical style of deeply-nesting callbacks using closures is the single greatest impediment to the understandability of Node programs, as well as being completely unnecessary.

For every:

```
a.doSomething(val, function(err,result){
  b.doSomethingElse(result,function(err,res){
    ...
  });
});
```

There is always a:

```
a.doSomething(val, onDoSomething);

function onDoSomething(err,res) {
  ...
}
```

My rule of thumb is: a new non-closure callback function is required for anything over three levels of nesting.

(Node.js really needs a style manual.)

Comment: I totally second you on the style manual. I'm going to suggest it on the mailinglist!

Answer (score 2):

After you learned how require works in node.js (pretty straightforward), as suggested by Kooilnc

You can take a look at the source code of the modules available for Node.js:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules

If you're planning to use Express (one of the most robust node.js framework out there) to develop your first node applications, you can take a look at its specific samples here:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples
(there's also an mvc sample)